# Database First Association With Compound Key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have two tables which I cannot make changes to and I would like a simple mapping:

**Employee Table**

- integer Id **KEY**
- varchar(10) EmployeeCode

**Address Table**

- varchar(10) EmployeeCode **KEY**
- varchar(30) AddressType **KEY**
- varchar(50) Line1
- varchar(50) Line2
- varchar(50) Line3
- varchar(50) Line4

I am having great difficulty mapping an `Address` property on the `Employee` entity.  The problem is that the `AddressType` can be either "Mailing" or "Billing". I only need the mailing address so I want the property to link to the mailing address.

Basically I need Entity Framework to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Address a ON e.EmployeeCode = a.EmployeeCode
                     AND a.AddressType = 'Mailing'
```

How do I get a nicely mapped `Address` property on my Employee entity?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I don't know, the database wasn't written by us so I am just having to deal with it.

Comment: could you use a view or stored proc to represent the association?